# Ubuntu - Work-around broken display

Tags: gnome, display, screen

I am on vaccation and my notebook-display broke.
The upper 25% of the screen are clearly visable (Thus I can post here)..
I recognized that the console (tty1,tty2,...) is almost clear. But But on gnome (i don't think its gnome-related) i can not see anything that is below a certain horizontal line. My question is what might be the difference between console and x-desktop or what might be the cause of the described failure (tough question tho) and how I may fix it for now

Comment: This sounds more like a broken graphics card or a broken screen.  Does absolutely nothing display on the remaining 75% of the screen?  Even when you switch to TTY and login and hit enter a few dozen times to get the screen to show a bunch of lines?

Comment: Sry for having been such unprecise... yes, the screen is phisically broken... On X-destop it shows some colors similar to that what is displayed on the "working" 25%. On TTY it displays everything almost correctly. No doubt that i need the screen to be replaced... but the fact that on command line everything is more readable lets me think about possible ways to fix it as there is no way to get the screen replaced yet... I wonder about the differences between command line and x-desktop (pixel refreshment etc)...